# Limit search in .NET Reflector to a particular assembly

Tags: .net, debugging, reflector

I tried googling for this without much success, so I thought I would come here. I am using Red Gate's [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) to explore some assemblies. Is there any way to limit the search to particular assemblies or namespaces?

For example, if I search for "table", I get a whole heap of results such as the `IFormattable` in the `System` namespace in the `mscorlib` assembly. Is there any way to limit this search without removing these libraries from the current list of libraries opened in .NET Reflector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get close to what you want without removing all of the assemblies from the tree. Since a click on the Assembly column header will change the sort order, you can easily see all the ones in `mscorlib` grouped together.

Of course, unlike removing assemblies from the tree, this will not improve the performance of the search operation. Note that you can use the File, Open List command to maintain multiple lists of assemblies that you can easily switch between.

Comment: Multiple lists seems to be the way to go. Surprising though, since reflector is mainly used for code exploration, I would have thought a more advanced search functionality would be built in.

Answer (score 1):

If the assembly has somewhat unique namespace you could include it in your search term.
For instance I very often do something along the lines:

MyCompany.MyProject.Abstracts IConfigurationProvider

Note the space between the namespace and the actual type name.
I know this is not perfect and relies on decent namespaces (my assembly names typically indicate the namespace), but still this signifficalnty improves the situation.